# How to access to some data before saving my django form?

Tags: django, validation

I'm building a tournament manager currently and I block on a step of my program because I don't have enough experience in Django.
So, basically I have a view that manage the add team system to a tournament. I have a model "Tournament" which contains a field that indicates the number of teams that I can have in a Category ("Category" is an other field). Between Category and Tournament there is a Many-to-One relationship. I also have a model "Team" and there is a Many-to-One relationship between Team and Category. So my question is how can I check if I can add or not the team in a category depending on the field in "Tournament" ? I specify that there can be the same category in two different tournaments.

**`views.py`**

```
def team_view(request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    tournaments = Tournament.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(pk=id)

    form_team = TeamCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    form_team.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(tournament=tournament)

    if form_team.is_valid():

        form_team.save()
        form_team = TeamCreationForm()
        form_team.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(tournament=tournament)

    context = {
        'tournaments': tournaments,
        'tournament': tournament,
        'form_team': form_team,
    }
    return render(request, "tournament_manage_team.html", context)
```

**`forms.py`**

```
class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.description

class TeamCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name                = forms.CharField(label='Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter the name of the team'}))
    category            = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = [
            'name',
            'category',
        ]
```

**`models.py`**

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    dateStart           = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    dateEnd             = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    nbMaxTeam           = models.IntegerField()
    # nameGymnasium     = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    # addressGymnasium  = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    sport               = models.ForeignKey(Sport, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user                = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Category(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    tournament  = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

class Team(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    totalpoints = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    position    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    matches     = models.ManyToManyField(Match, default=None, blank=True)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I suppose I have to check this in **`is_valid()`** method but how can I get the category that I'm selecting in my form and related to the tournament where I'm adding my team ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. As with any other validation, you define a `clean` method and then access `self.cleaned_data`.

Comment: How can I access to field "tournament" through the field "category" of my form ?

Comment: `self.cleaned_data['category'].tournament`

Comment: Ok, I think I'll be able to do something with this, thank you anyway !